# restricting rsync in daemon mode

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync

I'm trying to run rsync in daemon mode on one machine, called node0. I want the machine to accept connections only from node0 (self) or node1 (some other machine which is defined)

The only path I want to be available for use it /tmp/. So that any read/write operation to any other path should be disallowed, for any originatting machine.

I do not want user restrictions, nor rsync to run over ssh.

I've set up /etc/rsyncd.conf as following:

```
syslog facility = syslog
max verbosity = 3
log file = /var/log/mylog.log
port = 873

[Proj1]
path = /tmp/
include = /tmp/
exclude = *
comment = some comment
hosts allow = node0, node1
hosts deny = *
max verbosity = 3
log file = /var/log/filedistributer.log
```

I than execute rsync in daemon mode with the following command:

```
/usr/bin/rsync --daemon --config=/etc/rsyncd.conf --verbose
```

Than from node1 I run:
`rsync -a test.out node0:/tmp/` and it works correctly.

But if I run: `rsync -a max.out node0:/someOtherDir`  and it also works - where it should not.

If I go to a different machine and run:

```
rsync -a someFile.out root@node0.MYHOSTNAME:/someOtherDir
```

It asks me to authorize the ssh key, and enter password for root, after that I copies the file... It should not.

What am I missing? None of my requirments are met:

1. Rsync uses SSH, when it should not
2. Rsync does not restrict hosts.
3. Rsync does not restrict folders

The log file, despite the level 3 verbosity only has one line (per each daemon startup) in the form of:

> 2013/11/18 12:32:35 [22289] rsyncd version 3.0.6 starting, listening
>   on port 873

*Additionally another problem I encounter is that if I run the rsync command from node0 to node1, it still succeeds, even without me starting rsync in daemon mode on node1.*

Your help is appriciated.

Thanks,
Max.

Comment: There are two different ways for rsync to contact a remote system: using a remote-shell program as the transport (such as ssh or rsh) or contacting an rsync daemon directly via TCP. So when you contact it from node0 to node1 this is probably what you do, in this case the remote-shell invokes the rsync server on node1(with arbitrary port - you can check this to validate my assumption)

Comment: Use double colons to connect to the rsync daemon directly instead of having ssh start it. `rsync -a test.out node0::Proj1/` (host **::** share)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some digging what I came up with is that:

1. By default when running rsync it will try to use ssh as its transport, hence it ssh's to the destination machine and invokes rsync there. 
   To be used it will require valid credentials on the destination machine. There is no way to avoid this - other than removing the ssh daemon from the destination machine.
   In order to restrict rsync from working in this mode, it is actually required to restrict ssh or rsh (or whatever shell is used as transport) from accepting connections from unrelated hosts. Yet it will still be impossible to force the "white list" hosts to operate only on the desired folders in this mode.
2. My restrictions to rsync in daemon mode using rsyncd.conf are correct and they work, but in order to use tcp as the transport layer and not ssh, it is required to use rsync differently

   rsync rsync://node0/Proj1

This will actually make rsync go through a tcp connection and connect to the rsync daemon on the destination.

A very valueble source of information on how rsyn works can be found in the link below:
http://rsync.samba.org/how-rsync-works.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure the config file is actually red by the daemon when launched?
Try for example to deny all hosts and check if the rule applies.

Comment: It is read - since if I connect with rsync from the other node to this one, with:

rsync rsync://node0
I see the module I exposed in the config file. Thing is that even if I restrict all hosts, than the syntax from the question somehow works.

From what I've dug this could be due to rsync going through an SSH tunnel, and not going directly to the rsync daemon... I'm just unsure how to prevent this

Comment: the current version of rsync uses ssh by default so there is nothing to prevent here, you can if you want to change the remote shell to something else of course with the -e flag